# search within list to group elements by shared content

Tags: python, list

if I have list with this content

```
[MNA1
MNA3
MNA3_1
MNA3_2
MNA2
MPA3_3
MPA3_2
MPA3_1
MPA3
MPB]
```

how can I take all values that have the same first four chars in one group
example

```
MPA3_3
MPA3_2
MPA3_1
MPA3
```

must be in one group(list) or any other thing

Comment: that is not a list of strings

Comment: This not a Python list. Please post some actual data.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: its a list of objects and each object has object name as string

Comment: Can you put a sample some data you'd like to work on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have strings.

```
l = [
'MNA1',
'MNA3',
'MNA3_1',
'MNA3_2',
'MNA2',
'MPA3_3',
'MPA3_2',
'MPA3_1',
'MPA3',
'MPB'
]
```

you can do

```
values = set([elem[:4] for elem in l])
newlist = [[elem for elem in l if elem[:4]==x] for x in values]
```

or as a oneliner:

```
newlist = [[elem for elem in l if elem[:4]==x] for x in set([elem[:4] for elem in l])]
```

newlist looks like:

```
 [['MNA1'],
 ['MNA3', 'MNA3_1', 'MNA3_2'],
 ['MPA3_3', 'MPA3_2', 'MPA3_1', 'MPA3'],
 ['MPB'],
 ['MNA2']]
```

Comment: what if  this was list of objects and each object has name so I used for loop to print this list?

Comment: if its a list of objects with names you can replace elem[:4] with elem.getName()[:4]

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `groupby`,

```
In [13]: for g,l in groupby(lst,key=lambda x:x.split('_')[0]):
    ...:     temp = list(l)
    ...:     if len(temp) == 4:
    ...:         print temp
    ...:         
['MPA3_3', 'MPA3_2', 'MPA3_1', 'MPA3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of grouping your item together.

```
l = [
'MNA1',
'MNA3',
'MNA3_1',
'MNA3_2',
'MNA2',
'MPA3_3',
'MPA3_2',
'MPA3_1',
'MPA3',
'MPB'
]

new_dict = {}
for item in ls:
    key = item[0:4]
    if key in new_dict.keys():
        new_dict[key].append(item)
    else:
        new_dict[key] = [item]

print(new_dict)
```

Outputs:

```
{'MNA1': ['MNA1'],
 'MNA2': ['MNA2'],
 'MNA3': ['MNA3', 'MNA3_1', 'MNA3_2'],
 'MPA3': ['MPA3_3', 'MPA3_2', 'MPA3_1', 'MPA3'],
 'MPB': ['MPB']}
```